# Создание приложения для получения прямой ссылки

Tags: c#, post, url, link

Хочу сделать программу которая бы конвертировала ссылку (получение прямой ссылки), опишу алгоритм:

1. Пользователь в textbox вставляет такую ссылку `http://example.com/download/тутданные/file-name.jpg.html/`.
2. Программа их этой ссылки берет фрагмент (тутданные), присваивает какой-то переменной.
3. Отправляет post запрос на хост `http://example.com/download/getlink` с параметрами `sekret=тутданные,action=getlink_file,downloaded=1`
4. Получает ответ (переход по такому адресу `http://какой-то-сайт/api/web/getInstaller?transaction_id=79610604&token=b48aa6bae41a37394677dfe57d3f1a7a&return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fs1.test.ru%2Fu%2Fcdaba1f3138e2e72a3a119b391c52aa4%2F67c00066b6%2FYKuRUX22rvI.jpg`)
5. Из этой ссылки мы берем только эту часть `http%3A%2F%2Fs1.test.%2Fu%2Fcdaba1f3138e2e72a3a119b391c52aa4%2F67c00066b6%2FYKuRUX22rvI.jpg`
6. Открываем получившую ссылку открываем в браузере.

Как это реализовать? Если будите отправлять примеры, то комментируйте пожалуйста каждую строку.

Comment: Не взлетит. А если код браузера выставляет cookie? А если он проверяет IP? А если сгенерированная ссылка действительна только в течение 30 секунд?

Comment: Складывается впечатление, что это домашнее задание... Автор, вы хоть пытались? Или вам интересен лишь готовый результат, да ещё и с комментариями на каждую строку? ))

Comment: Куки здесь вообще не задействованы , ip тоже не проверяется, сгенерированная ссылка доступно более часа, все сделано очень примитивно.Делал подобную программу, только там был более легкий способ получить ссылку, а с post запросами не как не получается.

Comment: Реальную ссылку на какой-нибудь файл можно? Так в разы проще было бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить ответ должно быть по идее просто:

```
var uri = "http://example.com/download/тутданные/file-name.jpg.html/";
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
req.Method = "POST";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

string location;
using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
    {
        // редирект не пришёл, упс
        throw new AppropriateException();
    }
    location = resp.GetResponseHeader("Location");
}
```

Вытащить `return_url` тоже несложно:

```
var query = new Uri(location).Query;
var queryDict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
var returnUrl = queryDict["return_url"];
```

Но это всё очень хрупкий код. Он надеется на то, что редирект приходит «правильным» образом (а не, допустим, через javascript), что location будет правильным, и что в нём будет секция `return_url`.

(Ну и этот код практически не ловит ошибки и выполняет всё синхронно, что тоже неправильно.)